# Extract editing history from Microsoft Word documents?

Tags: text-mining, text, word

Is there a tool to computationally extract the editing history of a given Microsoft Word Document?

*I have been using Apache Tika, but can only extract the last version of the text, and meta-information about the initial and last edit – even if edits are still being tracked via Word.*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the belongs to another site in the Stack Exchange Network(Software Recommendation)

Comment: See this link:  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-word/possible-to-export-word-track-changes-information/e0dee9dc-aedb-41d3-92bf-8dc609cc75af